# Compare multiple column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so i have table with following data

### Table filter

```
product_id      filter_id     
51                 1
52                 2
51                 2
52                 1
52                 4
```

### Table description

```
group_id      filter_id     filter_name      group_name
1                 1             white          COlour   
1                 2             black           COlour   
1                 3             grey            COlour   
2                 4             formal          Style  
2                 5             casual         Style
```

If given set of filter id by user, i want to filter products like by grouping filter_id considering their group_id for ex. 
 `select * from filter where filter_id in (1,2) AND filter_id in (4,5)` when i use this query i get empty output

why i used IN twice here is because 1,2 belong to one filter_group and 4,5 belongs to different filter_group, groups and filters may be added in the table so i will be generating dynamic query using php depending on user selection.

Can anyone help me out in finding a solution for this problem, Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Please name your table example with table names

Comment: @MarcusH made the changes

Comment: Please provide the expected output as "filter products like by grouping filter_id considering their group_id for ex" is not clear

Comment: if i want the product id whose filter is of black or white colour and of style formal.

Comment: @GuillaumeThomas ive  added some columns for better understandings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for me:

```
select
..
......

where filter.product_id in
  (select a.product_id from filter a where a.filter_id in (1,2))
AND filter.product_id in 
  (select a.product_id from filter a where a.filter_id in(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provide, you need to do as many subqueries as groups on which you filter and use `inner join`  between those subqueries:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM
  ( SELECT product_id
   FROM filter
   WHERE filter_id IN (1,
                       2)) group1 // Here you select white or black products 
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT product_id
   FROM filter
   WHERE filter_id IN (4)) group2 // here products with Formal style
using(product_id) // Here both
```

Comment: I'm kinda a beginner in this stuff but can u help me integrate this query in my complete query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT oc_product.product_id, oc_product.image, oc_product.name, oc_product_option.option_id, oc_product.price
     
     
    FROM oc_product, oc_product_to_category, oc_product_option, oc_review $from 
    
    where  oc_product_option.product_id = oc_product.product_id
    AND  oc_product_to_category.category_id = $category_id
    AND oc_product_to_category.product_id = oc_product.product_id